# How to convert JSON Array to show in DataGridView vb.net

Tags: vb.net, firebase

I'm Having a trouble to convert my JSON database to show in DataGridView. I'll already change the JSON file. It always show a prompt message that it can't convert object of type "system.string" to type "Name.vb"

Here is my code:

```
Public Sub ShowRecord()
    Try
        Dim dtTable As New DataTable

        dtTable.Columns.Add("Name")

        dtTable.Columns.Add("Age")

        If clearDGVCol = True Then
            LeaveDataView.Columns.Clear()
            clearDGVCol = False
        End If

        Dim SRRecord = client.Get("Name/")
        Dim myJsonTool As New JavaScriptSerializer
        Dim myDeserializedItems = myJsonTool.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, Name))(SRRecord.Body)

        For Each dictItem As KeyValuePair(Of String, Name) In myDeserializedItems
            dtTable.Rows.Add(dictItem.Value.Name,
                             dictItem.Value.Age)
        Next

        LeaveDataView.DataSource = dtTable
        dtTableGrd = dtTable
    Catch ex As Exception
        If ex.Message = "One or more errors occurred." Then
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to firebase, check your network !", "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        ElseIf ex.Message = "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Then
            Dim dtTable As New DataTable
            dtTable.Columns.Add("Name")
            dtTable.Columns.Add("Age")
            LeaveDataView.DataSource = dtTable
            MessageBox.Show("Database not found or Database is empty.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If

    End Try
End Sub
```

Here is the JSON file:

```
{
  "Nico" : {
    "Age:" : "24",
    "Contact:" : "1234567890",
    "Name:" : "Nico Gonzales",
    "Password:" : "123",
    "Username:" : "nico"
  }
}
'''

'''
Here is my Name.vb file:
'''
    Public Class Name
        Public Property Name() As String = ""
        Public Property Age() As String = ""
        Public Property Contact() As String = ""
        Public Property Username() As String = ""
        Public Property Password() As String = ""
    End Class
'''
```

Comment: I see problems, but it's not clear just from the problems what you're hoping to do. Explain "I'm Having a trouble"

Comment: Sorry about that. I can't convert my JSON file so that the data can be view in the datagridview. I'm having a hard time because there are limited sources to find and compare the codes.

Comment: Show the full json returned by `client.Get("Name/")` - your code implies multiple but your example has only one. Or just show a respresentative example of the entire JSON

Comment: I'll updated the info above.

Comment: That's truly the full JSON? What's the value of SRRecord?

Comment: yes that's the full JSON file. There is no value of SRRecord.

Comment: It must have some value, because you deserialize its Body - what is the value of its Body?

Comment: The Value of the SRRecord is "{FireSharp.Response.FirebaseResponse}" and the value  of SRRecord.Body is "{""Age"":""24"",""Name"":""Nico Gonzales""}"